# How to extract specific values from Python Numpy array1 and from those values, create a new array2 with the same shape as array1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, extract

Let's say I have a 2D Numpy array called 'Z' shaped (90,360). Array Z has values that range 0 to 100.

How can I create a new Numpy array, called 'A', that extracts only specific Z-values (lets say where Z=60) and places those Z-values in the same A-indices as where it occurs in Z. In other words, array 'A' needs to contain only Z-values that are equal to 60 and also retain the same index value of where 'Z'= 60.

Comment: What about the other elements of `A`, the ones that don't match `Z`?

Comment: Those can be zero or Nan values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that array `a` will be zero in the spots where `z` is not 60 we get:

```
a = np.zeros_like(z)
mask = np.isclose(z, 60)
a[mask] = z[mask]
```

Comment: If `z` is an integer type, `z == 60` is fine. I suspect that `isclose` handles that for you anyway.